# Checkbox not binding to ng-model inside ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am rendering my `DataTable` the angular way, I added a select all `checkbox` at the top and per row I added a `checkbox` and number `textbox`.

If the `checkbox` per row is `checked` then the number `textbox` would be enabled.

The problem is that for example, I check selectAll then the `checkbox` per row would be checked but the number `textbox` remains disabled. I checked the value of the `checkbox` per row and it was false even though the `checkbox` was checked.

I cannot remove the `api.rows({search:'applied'})` code and just change the value of the `checkbox` per row using `for` or `angular.forEach` because for example the user `filters` the result using the `checkbox` and then the user clicked `selectAll` then it should only check the filtered results.

see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VskZdQSPqJdbe5RHrCfW?p=preview).

This was tagged duplicate but the problem is different. My problem was that I changed the prop of the checkbox per row in my datatable.

Comment: @BhaskarRajoriya the problem is different. My problem was that I changed the prop of the checkbox per row in my datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the `ng-model` value for each data row and not the `checked` prop of checkbox.

Angularjs is model driven, you should always change data, it will automatically reflect on UI as per bindings.

Please check this updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/usCzB7ZMxzpEW7HlJc4o?p=preview)

Comment: This fixed my ng-disabled problem but the selectAll checkbox should only check the filtered items. for example I searched 'Accountant', it will return two results so if I checked the selectAll checkbox it should only check the filtered items (the two results) but it checks all the results because the api search applied code is commented.